# Numbers on a Google Chart aren't loading on IE (pre-IE10)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-visualization, loading, onload

I've been tasked to fix a Google Chart issue that users (IE8 & IE9) have complained about.

Basically, I have a Google Chart on a "tab" on our front end.  I've made a static instance of our front end (saved the HTML on the browser) and distilled the problem down to the below HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ShowSection(strSectionName){
        document.getElementById('TAB_TIME').style.backgroundColor='white';
        document.getElementById('TAB_RESPONSES').style.backgroundColor='white';

        document.getElementById('SECTION_TIME').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('SECTION_RESPONSES').style.display='none';

        document.getElementById('TAB_'+ strSectionName).style.backgroundColor='lightblue';
        document.getElementById('SECTION_'+ strSectionName).style.display='table-row';
                }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body style="margin:20px;" onLoad="ShowSection('RESPONSES');">

        <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:1390px;" border="1" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td id="TAB_TIME"       onClick="ShowSection('TIME');">TIME SERIES</td>
                <td id="TAB_RESPONSES"      onClick="ShowSection('RESPONSES');">RESPONSES</td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="SECTION_RESPONSES">
                <td>Hello world</td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="SECTION_TIME" >
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <div style="border:1px solid black;" id="CHART_SALES_OVER_TIME_WEEKLY"></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                          function drawChart() {
                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                              ['Dummy data', 'Sales'],
                            ['1', 1],['2', 1],['3', 3],['4', 0]
                            ]);

                            var options = {
                              height: 600,
                              width: 1370
                            };

                            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('CHART_SALES_OVER_TIME_WEEKLY'));
                            chart.draw(data, options);
                          }
                    </script>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, if you fire that up, you'll see it's a representation of two tabs (using tables), by onLoad hiding 's, and onClick to swap between them.

Everything works as intended on most browsers when you click on the TIME SERIES "tab", in that you see numbers on the x- and y-axes; However, in IE8 and IE9, the numbers on the axes don't load.  The only exception to that is to change the body tag to point to the TIME SERIES tab onLoad, ie:

```
    <body style="margin:20px;" onLoad="ShowSection('TIME');">
```

Doing that makes IE load the numbers.  Can anyone explain to me what incompatibility in IE8 and IE9 is preventing the Google Chart from loading properly (ie. what's happening here!?), and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are drawing the chart inside a hidden div.  The Visualization API requires that all charts be drawn in visible divs in order to retrieve dimensional information accurately.  The easy way around this in your code is to remove the "onload" event handler from your page and call it from a "ready" event handler for the chart:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('CHART_SALES_OVER_TIME_WEEKLY'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    ShowSection('RESPONSES');
});
chart.draw(data, options);
```

When working with multiple charts, you want to initialize your tabs only when all have finished drawing, so you need to keep track of which charts are ready:

```
var chartsReady = [];
function setupReadyEvent(chart, index) {
    chartsReady[index] = false;
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        chartsReady[index] = true;
        var allReady = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < chartsReady.length; i++) {
            allReady = allReady && chartsReady[i];
        }
        if (allReady) {
            ShowSection('RESPONSES');
        }
    });
}

setupReadyEvent(chart1, 0);
setupReadyEvent(chart2, 1);
setupReadyEvent(chart3, 2);
```

Alternatively, if you are using a [Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#dashboardobject), you can trigger off the "ready" event of the dashboard:

```
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(dashboard, 'ready', function () {
    ShowSection('RESPONSES');
});
// bind charts and controls in Dashboard, eg:
dashboard.bind([control], [chart]);
dashboard.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: This worked great in the little example I've supplied, thank you asgallant!

Comment: This worked great in the little example I've supplied, thank you asgallant!

The actual live site has multiple Google Charts, and -- given my understanding, through your explanation -- whilst I thought adding your code above to each Google Chart would work, ultimately I had to add it only to the first instance, and then I put in a 'blank' addListener to the subsequent instance.

Despite being a work-around, it's all we have time/budget for, and it did the trick.  Thanks again asgallant!

Comment: With multiple charts, you should actually initialize the tabs only when all have finished drawing.  I'll modify my example above to give you an idea of how you can do that.